# UIWebView not picking up QuickType Text in an HTML input field in iOS 8.1.2

Tags: ios, input, uiwebview, quicktype

I have a UIWebView where I'm inputting text into an input tag on the HTML. However when I use QuickType on that text field, only what I've actually typed gets sent in the form.

For example, if I'm trying to type "Apple", and I only actually type "Ap" and select the word "Apple" on QuickType, only "Ap" is set.

For now I'm just disabling the QuickType feature on the input tag using autocorrect="off", but is there a way to actually recognize QuickType inputs on an input HTML text field?

Comment: I've also seen this in action. There are two events triggered: the first, with the suggested test added; the second, with the suggestion replaced by a 'space'.  I suggest building a minimal example and filing a bug report with Apple.